# expect interact with <<EOF not work properly

Tags: shell

i want a auto su script  but
expect  interact with <

this script work  properly

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 5
spawn su
expect "Password:"

send "123456\r"
interact

#expect "# "

#send "whoami"
```

but this  not  work

```
#!/bin/bash
su_user=$1
su_pwd=$2
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF

set time 30
spawn  su $su_user
expect  "assword" 
send  "$su_pwd\r"
send "whoami\r"
interact

EOF
```

after run the script  the user do not change

why dose  interact not work  with  <

Comment: Perhaps you send `$whoami` too early. You nevery _expect_ the `<` prompt to appear, but just send your command.

Comment: @user1934428  i just delete  `send "whoami\r"`, it's still not work

Comment: And the password is correct? Did you try to hard-code user and password? In your first variant, which you claim to work, you did not specify an explicit user name. Also, for testing I would put a sleep before sending the password. After all, you don't expect `Password:` (with colon), but send already after getting `assword` (without waiting for the colon).

Comment: @user1934428 thanks your advice .  but i ran the same command  with same username and password    ,and  just   replace  interact  in  this  script  with expect eof   , it's work  ,but it's just that I can't control it,so that i'm sure  the password is  correct

Comment: Well, the variable substitution should at least work (unless `su_user` contained a space, which is unlikely). I suggest that you run your program under `set -x`, to see what is going on, and also post the program where you have hard coded user name and password and where you claim it would work, and then we should find some difference between the two.

Comment: @ 杨雨翰 : Also, in your first program you set the timeout corretly with `set timeout`, and in the second version you used `set time` instead. I don't think this is the reason of your problem, but if you want to change an existing _expect_ script by embedding it as a _here_ document in bash, you really should copy it literally first, see that this works, and THEN start to replace your parameters by shell variables. BTW, why did you want to use a _here_ document? I think keeping it as separate _expect_ script is easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain that this is your problem but I think interact is getting the EOF from stdin and aborting.

I'm having a similar issue trying to do 
cmd | expect_script.

As my very simple testcase I'm trying to do 'read x; echo $x' on a remote server and "echo FRED" as my cmd but my script is aborting like this:

```
running read x; echo this is $x
send: sending "read x; echo this is $x\r" to { exp5 }
spawn id exp0 sent <FRED\n>
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
interact: spawn id exp0 not open
```

(You might find exp_internal 1 useful for debugging)